# Flutter application crashes when providing custom application class in Android's Manifest file

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on a Flutter application. I have to initialize an object in Application class in Android, and I have created a custom application class that is extending `FlutterApplication` class. I have provided the class name in Manifest file too but when I run the application it crashes.

Please suggest, how can I do that. Below is the code of application class and manifest file.

Thank You.

**Manifest file**

```
 <application
    android:name="com.example.app.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
 ...
 </application>
```

**MyApplication class**

```
package com.example.app;
import android.app.Application;
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;

class MyApplication extends FlutterApplication {

    @override
    public void onCreate() {
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The application class handles the context, environment setup etc during app start up process so along with manifest registration, you [must call `super.onCreate()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java#236) as stated:

> If you override this method, be sure to call {@code
>   super.onCreate()}.

so do

```
class MyApplication extends FlutterApplication {

    @override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate() // add this          
    }
}
```

Note: With `super.onCreate()`, there's no need to call `FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)`, as will be done by [FlutterApplication](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/example/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidalarmmanagerexample/Application.java)

```
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```